# cbind() Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows. What does it mean?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a data.frame from multiple .csv files, but when I try to bind them using cbind() I run into the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 10523, 8663
```

This is my code:

```
files <- list.files(, pattern = ".csv")

library (magrittr)
library (dplyr)

temp <- read.csv(files[1], sep = ";", header = TRUE)

temp$vl_despesa <- as.character(temp$vl_despesa)
temp$vl_despesa <- gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".", temp$vl_despesa)
temp$vl_despesa <- as.numeric(temp$vl_despesa)

ans <- temp %>%
  select(codigo_municipio_ibge, ds_municipio, ds_elemento, vl_despesa, ds_funcao_governo, ds_subfuncao_governo) %>%
  filter(ds_funcao_governo == "EDUCAÇÃO" & ds_subfuncao_governo == "ENSINO FUNDAMENTAL")

for (i in 2:length(files)) {
  temp <- read.csv(files[i], sep = ";", header = TRUE)

  temp$vl_despesa <- as.character(temp$vl_despesa)
  temp$vl_despesa <- gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".", temp$vl_despesa)
  temp$vl_despesa <- as.numeric(temp$vl_despesa)

  ans <- cbind(ans, temp %>%
    select(codigo_municipio_ibge, ds_municipio, ds_elemento, vl_despesa, ds_funcao_governo, ds_subfuncao_governo) %>%
    filter(ds_funcao_governo == "EDUCAÇÃO" & ds_subfuncao_governo == "ENSINO FUNDAMENTAL"))
}
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 0):

If the number of rows, differ `cbind` will result in error.  Instead of `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

```
library(rowr)
library(dplyr)
for (i in 2:length(files)) {
  temp <- read.csv(files[i], sep = ";", header = TRUE)

  temp$vl_despesa <- as.character(temp$vl_despesa)
  temp$vl_despesa <- gsub(pattern = ",", replacement = ".", temp$vl_despesa)
  temp$vl_despesa <- as.numeric(temp$vl_despesa)

  ans <- cbind.fill(ans, temp %>%
    select(codigo_municipio_ibge, ds_municipio, ds_elemento, 
          vl_despesa, ds_funcao_governo, ds_subfuncao_governo) %>%
    filter(ds_funcao_governo == "EDUCAÇÃO" &
         ds_subfuncao_governo == "ENSINO FUNDAMENTAL"), fill = NA)
}
```

Comment: when i try to install rowr, the console says the package ‘rowr’ is not available (for R version 3.6.3), there is some other way around this?

Comment: @dangelo you can use the github version (eitherr direrctly copying the function or install) https://github.com/cran/rowr/blob/master/R/rowr.R

Comment: i ran it as you said, but instead of binding into the same columns, it created new ones:

```
[1] "codigo_municipio_ibge"     "ds_municipio"             
   [3] "ds_elemento"               "vl_despesa"               
   [5] "ds_funcao_governo"         "ds_subfuncao_governo"     
   [7] "codigo_municipio_ibge.1"   "ds_municipio.1"           
   [9] "ds_elemento.1"             "vl_despesa.1"             
  [11] "ds_funcao_governo.1"       "ds_subfuncao_governo.1"
```

Comment: @dangelo `cbind` creates new columns, if you need to bind with the original column, you may nee `rbind`